# HTML5 Image preloading

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using the following:

```
 window.addEventListener("load", pageFullyLoaded, false);

function pageFullyLoaded(e) {
// run animation instructions/function here
}
```

So the time all objects are in the DOM, images, scripts etc have finished loading my animation instructions can be fired.

My questions now is in regards to image preloading:
In my CSS I have been using the following:

```
 body::after {
 content: url ("sprite.png");
 display: none;
 }
```

However, I am not really clear as to what the difference is in using or not using it, if the load event in the JS already waits on all the images to be available before the animation takes place? Is there a benefit in using this in the CSS?

Comment: Actually, the onload event doesn't include background images in CSS and I have my doubt about this too...

Comment: what does this has to do with HTML5? I see javascript here, not HTML. plain old-school javascript

Answer (score 2):

The load event doesn't care about CSS.  They may or may not be loaded by the time the load event fires; they may or may not be "lazy-loaded" only on request.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? It seems weird that the load event would fire before the CSS (and images) were all fully loaded.

Comment: I read here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload] that the load event fires once all images have finished loading. That's why I am confused as to if it would be necessary to add another call to preload images specifically - either via css or JS. Thanks!